# XSuperObject: what's wrong with this date field?

Tags: json, delphi, isodate, tdatetime, xsuperobject

```
unit fmainForm;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses XSuperObject;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var fileContents : string;
    job: ISuperObject;
    LDate: TDate;
    LValue: string;
    LFormat: TFormatSettings;
    LDouble: Double;
begin
  fileContents := '{' +
                  '  "Id": "POS-1",' +
                  '  "Employer": {' +
                  '    "Name": {' +
                  '      "Normalized": "Acme"' +
                  '    }' +
                  '  },' +
                  '  "IsSelfEmployed": false,' +
                  '  "IsCurrent": true,' +
                  '  "StartDate": {' +
                  '    "Date": "2020-03-01",' +
                  '  },' +
                  '  "EndDate": {' +
                  '    "Date": "2021-06-08",' +
                  '  },' +
                  '}';

  job := SO(fileContents);

  if Assigned(job['Id']) then
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Job Id = ' +  job['Id'].AsString);

  if Assigned(job['Employer.Name.Normalized']) then
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Employer name = ' + job['Employer.Name.Normalized'].AsString);

  if Assigned(job['StartDate.Date']) then

    Memo1.Lines.Add('Start date = ' + job['StartDate.Date'].AsString);

  if Assigned(job['EndDate.Date']) then
    Memo1.Lines.Add('End date = ' + job['EndDate.Date'].AsString);
end;

end.
```

Most of it works. E.g `job['Id'].AsString` evaluates to `'POS-10'`, etc.

***But*** `job['StartDate.Date'].AsString` evaluates to `'43891'` and EndDate to `'44355'`. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

That's

> Job Id = POS-1
> Employer name = Acme
> Start date = 43891
> End date = 44355

Comment: You don't want to use `.AsDate()` I guess.

Comment: `43891` and `44355` look like `TDate` values interpreted as integers. Are you sure you are parsing//retrieving the fields as plain strings and not as `TDate/Time`s? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Are these trailing commas accepted?

Comment: @Remy I added an MRE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [XSuperObject's source code](https://github.com/onryldz/x-superobject), it turns out that by default, XSuperObject will process a String field as a Date/Time field if the string value resembles a valid date/time string (which it does, in this situation).

In Delphi, a `TDate(Time)` is implemented as a `Double`.  You are seeing XSuperObject parsing your JSON's `StartDate` and `EndDate` fields as if they were `TDate` values, not plain `String` values.  And then, when you call `.AsString` on those fields, you are getting back the numeric representation of those `TDate` values, not the original `String` data.

You *can* disable this behavior, however the `SO()` function does not allow you to do so. You will have to construct a `TSuperObject` object directly, so you can pass `False` to its `CheckDate` parameter (which is `True` by default), eg:

```pascal
//job := SO(fileContents);
job := TSuperObject.Create(fileContents, False);
```

Comment: Also, "`Looking at XSuperObject's source code,`". I hate it when I have to do that. Whatever happened to documentation (of which X-SuperObejct has precious little, as does so much other software which could be extremely useful, but which I will only look at as a last resort if the docs are poor /rant)?  Thanks again, Remy

Answer (score -1):

`TDate` is just a normal `Double` type.

When you do `AsString`, in reality you convert the double value as string.

You will see that your field contain a TDate and not a string by doing :

```
LType := job['StartDate.Date'].DataType; // dtDate
```

If you want to get the date value as string, you need to use `DateToStr` :

```
  if Assigned(job['StartDate.Date']) and (job['StartDate.Date'].DataType = dtDate) then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Start date = ' + DateToStr(job['StartDate.Date'].AsDate));
  end;
```

Comment: While this looks like it will work, I need to use `job['StartDate.Date']` in place of `cDate `.  I don't know if that is `cDate .AsString`, or `cDate .AsDouble` or something else. I will play around and get back to you

Comment: While this answer contains useful info about formatting dates in general, it does nothing at all to address the OP's particular issue. So I'm voting to close.

Comment: @remy, before you vote to close, please note that I posted a minimum reproducible example, as you requested. I fell that that ought to help elicit an answer.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I voted to close this particular answer, not your question as a whole.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica updated answer with your MRE