# X-SuperObject thinks that non existent keys exists

Tags: json, delphi, xsuperobject

There's code a minimum reproducible example in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75290180/xsuperobject-whats-wrong-with-this-date-field#75290180). Please let me know if you want it copied here.

Basically, I noticed that this code:

```pascal
if Assigned(job['Employer.Name.Normalized']) then
   Memo1.Lines.Add('Employer name = ' + job['Employer.Name.Normalized'].AsString);
```

was adding an empty string to the memo.

Hardly surprising, as the JSON looks like this:

```json
                    "Id": "POS-10",
                    "Employer": {
                        "Location": {
                            "CountryCode": "UK",
                            "Municipality": "Bradford"
                        }
                    },
                    "IsSelfEmployed": false,
                    "IsCurrent": false,
                    ... etc
```

So, why does `Assigned(job['Employer.Name.Normalized'])` evaluate to true?

Note that `Assigned(job.O['Employer'].O['Name'].O['Normalized'])` gives the same result, but, AFIAK, it's just syntactic sugar as how it is written.

So, I tried random keys: `Assigned(job['StackOverlow])` evaluates to `true`, as does `Assigned(job['Why is this not false???'])`

What am I doing wrongly? And how to I detect if a key actually exists in the `ISuperObject` which was obtained from my JSON?

Comment: You are using a derived work. Did you try with the original which can be found at https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject.

Comment: The GitHub page says that it is no longer maintained, which is why I chose X-SuperObject. But, I can't believe it is so flawed
 Much more likely that I am doing something wrongly. I'd no answers, I will try your suggestion

Comment: "*Please let me know if you want [code from other question] copied here*" - yes, please. StackOverflow questions are meant to be self-contained. They can certainly reference each other, but they should contain all relevant details in themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## This is working as designed.

Looking at [XSuperObject's source code](https://github.com/onryldz/x-superobject), it turns out that when you reference a member object or array, and that member doesn't exist, XSuperObject creates a new member. This lets users easily create new JSON documents.

To search for a member without creating it, you can use the `Contains()` method instead, eg:

```
if job.Contains('Employer') then
begin
  emp := job.O['Employer'];
  if emp.Contains('Name') then
  begin
    nam := emp.O['Name'];
    if nam.Contains('Normalized') then
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Employer name = ' + nam.S['Normalized']);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, as always, Remy. It's interesting to note that for nested JSOM, I can't use `job.Contains('Employer.Location')`, but that `job.O['Employer'].Contains('Location')` is fine.

BTW, do you know this form reading the code? Isn't there any decent documentation?

Comment: "*BTW, do you know this form reading the code?*" - yes. "*Isn't there any decent documentation?*" - I don't know, ask the author